# How do I convert a number (as a String) to an array of bytes in Java?

Tags: java, string, arrays, converters

I'm creating a method specific method for a java project i'm working on.
The UML given specifies the return type to be of `static byte[]` that accepts the arguments `(String, byte)`

So far, looks like this:

```
public static byte[] convertNumToDigitArray(String number, byte numDigits) {

}
```

This method is supposed to convert a number (as a String) to an array of bytes.  The ordering must go from most to least significant digits.  For example, if the 
number String is “732” then index 0 of the array should contain 7.
The last argument (numDigits) should match the length of the 
string passed in.

How do I do this?

Comment: If the value of `numDigits` can be inferred from the value of `number`, why are both required?

Answer (score 3):

Each character in the string can be retrieved using `charAt()`. The char can be converted to its digit value by subtracting, eg:

```
char c = number.charAt(0);
byte b = c - '0';
```

Comment: Yea this is certainly a nice trick; too many people are tempted to use `Integer.parseInt` (or something similar) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the 2nd parameter and do something like this:

```
public static byte[] convertNumToDigitArray(String number) {
    if (number != null && number.matches("\\d*") {
        byte[] result = new byte[number.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            result[i] = Byte.parseByte("" + number.charAt(i));
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must be numeric only");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why we need such complex code here.

What's wrong with just using the methods that come with the JDK

```
public static byte[] convertNumToDigitArray(String number, byte numDigits) {
    byte[] bytes = number.getBytes();
    Arrays.sort(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

If the sorting isn't what you meant, just remove that line.

Comment: Will using the getBytes() method store each digit of 'number' in ascending indexes?